# Stubborn Wireless Driver - Losing Connection Randomly (High Ping Values and Lots of Timeouts)

Tags: networking, windows-10, wireless-networking, drivers

The problem started about a couple weeks ago and it evolved over time.

Problem setup: Surfing the internet over my Lenovo Ideapad 520 Laptop via WiFi.

Initially the problem spawned randomly, surfing the internet then the connection drops and the Chrome Dinosaur appears, even though the Wifi icon down in the tray show no problems and that it is connected.

The problem was only solvable via Windows Diagnostics which in turns just restarts the Wireless Adapter.

The problem started appearing often.

Ping values to google.com was:

```
Reply from 216.58.213.174: bytes=32 time=86ms TTL=47
Reply from 216.58.213.174: bytes=32 time=95ms TTL=47
Reply from 216.58.213.174: bytes=32 time=86ms TTL=47
•
•
•
```

Then I reloaded youtube (or any site, just "starting to actually use the internet"), this happened:

```
•
•
•
Request Timed Out.
Request Timed Out.
Reply from 216.58.213.174: bytes=32 time=1900ms TTL=47
Request Timed Out.
Request Timed Out.
Request Timed Out.
Request Timed Out.
Reply from 216.58.213.174: bytes=32 time=3958ms TTL=47
Reply from 216.58.213.174: bytes=32 time=894ms TTL=47
Reply from 216.58.213.174: bytes=32 time=2452ms TTL=47
Request Timed Out.
Request Timed Out.
Request Timed Out.
Reply from 216.58.213.174: bytes=32 time=1731ms TTL=47
Request Timed Out.
Request Timed Out.
Request Timed Out.
Reply from 192.168.1.7: Destination host unreachable.
Reply from 192.168.1.7: Destination host unreachable.
General Failure.
General Failure.
General Failure.
•
•
•
```

And when I look at the Wifi Icon in the tray, it show the asterisk sign (meaning it is not connected to a network but there are available networks)

And then it show the red X icon (meaning wifi is turned off).

And then the wifi icon is gone, and the LAN icon appears with also a red icon (because I'm not connected an ethernet).

The problem appeared today even after a boot from shutdown, directly after Windows Booted, youtube video started for a couple of seconds (when ping values were low) and the above ping values happened again (high ping values and lots of time outs).

I tried the following:

- running windows diagnostics

  - before: this fixed the problem for a relatively long time span (like
    a whole day)
  - today: fixed the problem for two seconds and as soon as I closed the window it happened again.
- updating drivers

  - I updated those drivers via the update automatically button, windows told me that it had the latest drivers
  - qualcomm atheros qca9377 wireless network adapter
  - realtek pcie gbe family controller
  - updated manually by downloading the latest version from Lenovo's Support Site
  - update manually by removing -> restarting windows -> reinstalling -> restarting windows
  - updated using driver easy app
- performed NETWORK RESET from the windows settings (the new windows 10 settings)
- resetting network via CMD (netsh codes sequence - googled it)
- Ticking of `Allow PC to turn of this driver to save power`.
- Modifying power settings to let Wireless Driver have "Maximum Performance"

Those are full list of Network Drivers available on my PC: https://i.stack.imgur.com/90YOt.jpg

Each time the problem was gone for a brief time, and then it came back randomly.

Also I'd add:

For a time period, the problem appeared by default each and every time I let windows go to sleep/hibernate.

Two months ago I bought a Samsung SSD and cloned Windows to it via Magician. When I booted from the SSD Sound driver was not well and Wifi had this issue and was solved by Updating the Driver. The problem did not appear again till now.

For now, I'm using Wifi just fine, as I mentioned, the problem respawns randomly and as default when booting from sleep or hibernate state.

Please help, I've ran out of options, and now I'm using my laptop perfectly fine on ethernet, portability is not an option for now.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: All installed drivers were from the official Lenovo Support Website.

Comment: I'm guessing this is the latest driver from Lenovo. What version of the driver do you have? You may want to roll back a version, or try getting atheros drivers from another source. It definitely sounds like something happened with the HDD clone. When you go to tinker with the drivers, make sure you totally uninstall the card, reboot and load the alternative ones. See if these are any different,https://www.ath-drivers.eu/download-driver-for-Atheros-chipset-with-id-104-and-Windows10-64bit.html